# Android studio latest version 3.1.3 show in file explorer not working

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio latest version 3.1.3 show in file explorer  not working. Right click any class select show in file explorer or  build apk to locate its path its not working . previous versions are working fine latest studio unable to find its file explorer path.

Comment: Downgrade to the last stable build.

Comment: downgrade to 3.0.1 its stable build.